# How to get access to a subclass when the other class only knows the superclass?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, oop, object

I have a C# Windows Forms Application form1.cs with a Class Library (DLL) called class1.cs. Now on the UI side I do the following:

```
using System;
...
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace UI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MyLibraryClass mlc = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mlc = new MyLibraryClass(this);
        }

        public void aMethod() {
            Console.Write("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

In the Class Library I take the Form reference and want to call the method within, but I don't have access to it:

```
...
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class MyLibraryClass
    {
        private Form _form;

        public MyLibraryClass(Form form)
        {
            this._form = form;
            this._form.aMethod(); //Not working!
        }
    }
}
```

The reason as I understand it is that my ClassLibrary1 only knows Form but not Form1 and hence cannot call methods from Form1. The problem is, the UI knows the Class Library but not the other way around, since that would create a ring dependency as you certainly know. But how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You already have a dependency by relying on the fact that your `_form` object will have a `aMethod` method anyway.

Comment: Not directly related to your question here, but your intended code path has a bit of an issue- the constructor of Form1 is instantiating a MyLibraryClass object, which then calls a method on Form1 BEFORE the constructor of Form1 is complete. This may be an issue if the constructor of Form1 still has initialization to do- there isn't any shown here, but this appears to be a snippet rather than your entire code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead depeding of `Form` you can create an interface.

```
public interface IMyInterface {
    void aMethod();
}
```

`Form1` will *implement* the interface we created

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMyInterface
{
    MyLibraryClass mlc = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mlc = new MyLibraryClass(this);
    }

    public void aMethod() {
        Console.Write("Test");
    }
}
```

In `MyLibraryClass` now you will depend on the interface not the form. This way `MyLibraryClass` can use any form that **respect the contract** and we make sure that in `MyClassLibrary` will never be passed any *intruder* form.

```
public class MyLibraryClass
{
    private IMyInterface _form;

    public MyLibraryClass(IMyInterface form)
    {
        this._form = form;
        this._form.aMethod(); // now is work :)
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. The interface will be created in *Class Library* project (where `MyClassLibrary` is created).
2. I recommend you to take a look on **SOLID principles**.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. But Is this the general approach in Windows Forms, if one wants to call UI events from a class library? Say I want to change the Text in a TextBox from the DLL, I have to call setters using an interface?

Comment: @Ian you should look up what an interface is... this is good practice for C# and programming in general (winforms is irrelevant here) - Well written WinForms projects will use interfaces just like any other well written C# project. Your next point of call should be to learn the solid principles.

Comment: @Ian You can easily make a method in interface, but the right solution in this case is MVP (Model-View-Presenter) architecture, i recommend to take a look on this.

Comment: Yes, apparently I'm too familiarized with the simplicity of procedural programming. I will have a look at SOLID, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Circular dependencies are something you will want to avoid whenever possible, but let's assume you still need this.

The easiest solution would be to put the `MyLibraryClass` and `Form1` in the namespace, so you can replace the `Form` type parameter with a `Form1`. If you want to keep things nicely separate however, you will have to add a new type.

In you library you would have to add an interface that contains that method.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void aMethod();
}
```

If you then change the parameter to an `IMyInterface` instead, you have access to that method. If you need access to normal `Form` methods or the `aMethod` is always the same, you could opt for an abstract class that inherits from `Form` too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you should enforce *statically* the `Form1` class in the argument list:

```
public MyLibraryClass(Form1 form)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you cannot (which is often the case when several assemblies are used) you should test and cast *dynamically*:

```
public MyLibraryClass(Form form)
{
    if (form is Form1)
    {
        (form as Form1).aMethod();
    }
}
```

**BUT YOU REALLY SHOULD** honor the [**DIP** (Dependency inversion principle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), instead: *depend from abstractions*. Implement an interface and depend from that instead of `Form1`.

But if you've had the issue in the first place, you probably haven't cleared out for yourself how dependencies are organized between assemblies or, worse, don't know exactly why some answers propose to use interfaces.

Read the link above to know more about why, because your problem really is not about **HOW** but **WHY**.

Comment: Abstracting to an interface would be much better than adding a dependency to a concrete class, this is bad practice.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul: this is not bad practice, this is **very** bad practice. But it is a quick fix. To solve the actual problem the OP should study the theory first then implement the solution, which takes more time by far. That's why my answer has both facets: quick and dirty and the actual solution if a link to the theory behind it. That's better than just saying "use an interface" because the OP will not understand WHY he should.

Comment: You are providing bad advice with the hope that the OP learns from his mistake at a later date? Seriously? Why have you not mentioned the correct and preferred way of solving the solution?

Comment: Actually, I've provided the correct solution (which is **NOT** writing an interface but studying SOLID). For your pleasure I've rephrased 4 words and emphasized them so that it's not possible to misread my answer. Thank you for showing me where I've not paid enough attention. You can upvote now.

Comment: Sorry @pid, this does not deserve an upvote. The answer is confusing and not really relevant, "If you can, you should enforce statically the Form1 class in the argument list:" ... No he should not, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions

```
public interface IMethod
{
void aMethod();
}

public partial class Form1 : Form,IMethod

public MyLibraryClass(IMethod form)
    {
        this._form = form;
        this._form.aMethod(); 
    }
```